# On a mid-2011 iMac, how do I use Bluetooth on Windows 8?

Tags: imac, bluetooth, windows

I installed Windows 8 over a Boot Camp installation of Windows 7 on my mid-2011 iMac. By and large it's worked perfectly, UX issues notwithstanding, apart from the rather critical part of a complete lack of Bluetooth. This means I can't use my Apple Wireless Keyboard.

In Device Manager, I can't see any item that's related to Bluetooth, and in I'm not able to add any devices. I've tried re-installing the latest Boot Camp drivers, but I'm a bit lost at this point.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp is currently only meant for Windows 7, and the drivers are only meant for Windows 7. Maybe use Parallels or VirtualBox instead for Windows 8 for now.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had some Bluetooth device issues in Windows 8.

I found that booting into OS X and removing the paired device from OS X, then booting into Windows 8 allowed me to pair the device. Remember to boot back into OS X and pair the device against once it is working in Windows.

I also replaced the Broadcom drivers as well.

I wrote about this here: [Apple Wireless Keyboard Windows 8 problem](http://www.datamirage.nl/overige/apple-wireless-keyboard-windows-8-problem/)